# Broken Packages after installing AWN Lucido from official PPA

Tags: package-management, awn

After Downloading AWN Lucido Build the packages containing the AWN Applets won't install resulting in broken packages, is there a way to fix this mess?

EDIT:Well, the output is in Spanish and *SOMEHOW* the broken packages are no longer there
now it says the packages don't exist

```
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
El paquete awn-applets-c-core-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

El paquete awn-applets-python-core-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

El paquete awn-applets-c-extras-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

El paquete awn-applets-python-extras-trunk no está disponible, pero algún otro paquete hace referencia
a él. Esto puede significar que el paquete falta, está obsoleto o sólo se
encuentra disponible desde alguna otra fuente

E: El paquete «awn-applets-c-core-trunk» no tiene candidato de instalación
E: El paquete «awn-applets-c-extras-trunk» no tiene candidato de instalación
E: El paquete «awn-applets-python-core-trunk» no tiene candidato de instalación
E: El paquete «awn-applets-python-extras-trunk» no tiene candidato de instalació
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of the error?

Comment: Run the following, `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: You can get the error messages in English by prefixing the command like this: sudo LANG=C apt-get update

Comment: Run the above commands one by one in terminal.If you get any error.Just post the error here using pastebin.

Comment: oh,well that got the packages fixed, however i still can't install the applets it says that the package couldn't be found or they only make a reference to it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix broken packages type the following in terminal,

`sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

`sudo apt-get update`

To install **AWN Lucido** type the following in terminal,

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:awn-testing/ppa && sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator-trunk avant-window-navigator-data-trunk python-awn-trunk awn-settings-trunk awn-applets-python-core-trunk python-awn-extras-trunk awn-applets-python-extras-trunk awn-applets-c-core-trunk awn-applets-c-extras-trunk`

Comment: seems like i added a ppa that only contained the AWN "core" packages ,thanks